# Any way I can interact with a jQuery animation queue? - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

**Any way I can interact with a jQuery animation queue?**

I would like to be able to use an animation as if it were a movie of some sort, enabling me to rewind, fast forward, or even play the animation from a certain relative time.

---

I understand if this might be way too complicated to achieve, but for me it's worth asking and finding out. It would be very interesting to discover if this is possible. :)

---

Any ideas? =)

Comment: Possible? Yes, most certainly :) With jQuery's animation queue, I doubt not. jQuery's animation queue is just a list (queue) of functions. Once a function is done, it is taken off the queue. To be able to rewind, fast forward, or jump to a particular time, you need to look at the problem from a different angle. It's not about just piling up functions anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, there's no real support for this.

The reason is in how it works, it's a simple (well, as simple as possible) *forward-only* model:
[`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is done via a [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) for most things ([see source here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L338)).  It's a simplistic calculation in most cases, we need to go from value `x` to value `y` over `n` milliseconds.  The timer for jQuery happens every 13ms, every animation in progress updates (moves a step) every 13 ms.  It divides the ([duration/total time](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L418)) and [calls the update step](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L298) for the element to set it's style value for that [step](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L368).

You can't "fast-forward" really, as you'd have to adjust properties that aren't exposed once you kick off the animation.  You can skip to the end (via [`.stop(boo, true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)) of any animation, or [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) and [`.dequeue()`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) when needed...or even mess with the queue directly, at [`$.data(element,'fxqueue')`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/queue.js#L8), but that's it.  As for rewind...well, animations are cleaned up ([via a `.dequeue()` move](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L263)) so that's out too (besides the interval calculations all being forward-looking).

So no, there's no way to do this, at least not with the built-in animation system.  That's not to say it's not possible, rather that the code already written in jQuery core won't help you much here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your bottomless bucket of knowledge!

Comment: Quick question, is this: `fxeueue` a typo? I'm assuming you *meant* `fxqueue`, but I'm hesitant to edit without verifying. =/